# mouse over effect is not working

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

I have a strange issue here. I have a hidden element (display hidden) that I want to show when I mouseover another element. The javscript seems to do the job, but still nothing happens when the element changes from display: hidden; to display: block;

This is my html part:

```
<div id="cart_block" class="block exclusive" style="display: none;">
    a bunch more code in here, but I don't suppose I need to display that
</div>
```

Since it is in a smarty tpl file i've used literal to the javascript. It looks like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
    document.getElementById('header_user').onmouseover=function(){
        document.getElementById('cart_block').style.display='block';
    };
    document.getElementById('header_user').onmouseout=function(){
        document.getElementById('cart_block').style.display='none';
    };
{/literal}
```

You can see it at http://www.jiblab.dk . If you watch the element with id cart_block you should see that when you mouseover the basket in the top-right corner the style tag changes, but it stays hidden. If I remove style="display: none" from the above html, it shows my element, so in my head this should work.

Comment: Even after setting these styles on it: `display:block; margin:0; position:absolute; float:left; top:0px; left:0px; width:100px; height:100px;`, I can't get it to show up. No idea what's messing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the #cart_block element is in another div that has `display:none` set.

The following block needs .top-header .sf-contener removing from the definition, either that or move the cart_block element out of this element

```
.top-header #currencies_block_top, .top-header #header_links, .top-header #search_block_top, .top-header .sf-contener {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I only have these two options? The thing is I am not very good around prestashop - The elements you refer to is both called with prestashop's hook_top call, så to move it out I guess I'd had to add a new hook and attach the cart_block to that. I don't know how :( anything else I can consider doing?

Comment: I added visibility: hidden; to the specific elements in the container and removed display: block; from the container. This solved the issue. Thank you so much! I didn't know that I had to take this into account, so thank :)

Answer (score 0):

Use document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

document.getElementById('header_user').onmouseover=function(){
        document.getElementById('cart_block').style.display='block';
    };
    document.getElementById('header_user').onmouseout=function(){
        document.getElementById('cart_block').style.display='none';
    };


});
```

> ```
> <div id="header_user" style="width:100px; height:20px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
>
> <div id="cart_block" class="block exclusive" style="display: none;">
>     a bunch more code in here, but I don't suppose I need to display that
> </div>
> ```

Comment: The function is called, so I don't think using doc-ready is the solution